# Cannot get options from specific select

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm using `cheerio` and `nodejs` for scrape all the countries available on a site, essentially I did:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const options =
{
    uri: 'https://uk.soccerway.com/',
    transform: function(body)
    {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
};

rp(options)
  .then(($) =>
  {
    $('#navbar-left > div:eq(2) > select > option').each(function() 
    {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
  }).catch((err) =>
  {
      console.log(err);
  })
```

I want get all the coutnries of Club Domestic, unfortunately my code return this:

> SyntaxError: unmatched pseudo-class :eq

what is that?

**UPDATE**

new code (iteration will not start):

```
request('https://uk.soccerway.com/', function(err, resp, html)
{
  if (!err)
  {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var countriesMenu = find($, '#navbar-left > div:eq(2) option');

    $(countriesMenu).each(function()
    {
      console.log($(this).val());
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/429 you can use https://github.com/watson/cheerio-eq to get support for the `:eq` selector

Comment: but I'm not using the eq class, could be a jquery selector problem?

Comment: The `$` is cheerio in your case. And cheerio has not implemented the `:eq` selector

Comment: as I said if I remove the jquery selector I have no error

Comment: Right... That is the source of your error. If you want to use `:eq` you will need `cheerio-eq`

Comment: ok I fixed the error thanks but still no option is printed why

Comment: How did you fix the error?

Comment: I have installed the missing class using `npm install cheerio-eq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the psuedo-class :eq is not supported in cheerio. You're not using jQuery here, the $ is the cheerio object.

Here's a plugin you can use: https://github.com/watson/cheerio-eq

Answer (score 0):

The :eq pseudo-class is not implemented. Calling .eq() should work, though.

Comment: You have copied the shared resource from the comments

Comment: Yes, whats the problem?

Comment: That's the problem!

Comment: as you can see from my code I'm not using the eq class, could be a jquery problem? if I remove the jquery all working without error..

Comment: @Ele Coping is forbidden?

Comment: @ArturP. no, is not.  However, is a waste of time this kind of answer when you've even didn't add more information about how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Ele Ok, sorry, you are right. I will try improve my answers to be more descriptive